# Getting the IP of the interface that received a recvfrom() UDP packet (Microsoft)

Tags: winsock, multihomed

Using recvfrom() on a socket bound to INADDR_ANY on a Microsoft multihomed PC.
when recvfrom() gets an UDP packet: how can I find the Interface (IP) that received the packet?

Comment: Microsoft PC? That's a pretty wide range of possibilities, I'm assuming Windows - but still, what version? Win 3.11 and Win 7 are *slightly* different. Also, what have you tried? What results did you expect? What did you get instead?

Comment: --for some reason I cannot edit the original post--
using recvfrom() from win2000 (I cannot use WSARecvMsg()) to Win7 
so far I couldn't find anything to do this

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know the receiving IP when a single listening socket is bound to multiple IPs.  Instead of binding a single socket to `INADDR_ANY`, you can query the machine's list of local IPs using `GetAdaptersInfo()` and/or `GetAdapterAddresses()`, then create a separate listening socket for each IP.  You can use `getsockname()` to know which IP a given socket is bound to, but only when that socket is bound to a specific IP, not multiple IPs.